# When does JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(String, JsonSerializerOptions) return null?

Tags: c#, json, .net, system.text.json

According to the official [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.jsonserializer.deserialize?view=net-8.0#system-text-json-jsonserializer-deserialize-1(system-string-system-text-json-jsonserializeroptions)), the method `JsonSerializer.Deserialize<TValue>(String, JsonSerializerOptions)` has a return value of `TValue?`. However, the documentation unfortunately does not mention in which cases `null` is returned, and I have not been able to find such a scenario.

For example, for the following code (using the default value for the `JsonSerializerOptions` parameter):

```
record Test(string Whatever);
...
string json = ...;
Test? result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(json);
```

when is `result` set to `null`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For example [`null` JSON literal](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc8259#section-3) will result in the corresponding object being deserialized as `null`:

```
string json = "null";
Test? result = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<Test>(json); 
Console.WriteLine(result is null); // "True"
```

Comment: I think that was the fastest response I have ever witnessed. Thank you!